# How to use model.predict_proba() for loaded models

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, prediction, multiclass-classification

I am beginner in Machine Learning and I have built an image classification model based on VGG16 and tuned the last layers to my classification problem. There are 8 classes in total. Then I saved the model and want to use it again for predictions via:
`model = load.model(mymodel)`
But now I want to know with which percentage probability the classes were detected. Preferably the top 3. If I understood it correctly, I can't use `model.predict_proba()` or `model.predict_classes()` with a loaded model. How do I get the percentages?

Thats my Code for prediction so far:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os


model = models.load_model('mymodel')

# prediciton for test image
img_path = '...test.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size = (224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)
x /= 255. 


y_prob = model.predict(x)
y_classes = y_prob.argmax(axis = -1)

print(y_classes)
```

Comment: Why do you think you even need that function, or that is it not available? Please add all context to your question.

Comment: Most probable your model will output per-class probabilities when you call `.predict(...`

Comment: When using my code it outputs an integer for my class which is fine. I can add a data frame to it. But I want to see the percentage of the prediction. Like "2" , 0,9645